# How can I unzip the newest file in a directory in a BAT file?

Tags: build-process, batch-file, unzip

I am working on a build system.  The build system posts the results as a zip file in a directory.  Unfortunately I have no easy way to know the name of the zip file, because it is timestamped.  For the next operation, I must decompress this zip file to some specific location and then do some more file operations.

I guess I could change the build system so I specify the name of the result zip file from the command line, however, I though it might be easiest just to find out which one is the newest file and unzip it (if the previous process is successful).

How can I issue an unzip command that will only take effect on the newest zip file in the directory, ignoring all others?

EDIT: I decided to use the capabilities in ANT for this task instead. However, it is still a neat trick to have up the sleve...  Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should do it:

```
FOR /F usebackq %%i IN (`DIR /B /O-D *.ZIP`) DO UNZIP %%i && GOTO DONE || GOTO DONE
:DONE
```

This works as follows:

- `DIR /B /O-D *.ZIP` lists all ZIP files in reverse date order in a "bare" - i.e. name only - format.
- `FOR /F usebackq` is used to loop over the output of the command.
- `&& GOTO DONE || GOTO DONE` makes sure the `UNZIP` is only run for the first file.  You need both `&&` (and) and `||` (or) in case the unzip fails for some reason.

You'll need to change `UNZIP %%i` for whatever unzip command you want to use.

**EDIT**
The above will work as long as the Zip filename doesn't contain any spaces.  If you want to handle filenames with spaces, use the following variant:

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%i IN ('DIR /B /O-D *.ZIP') DO UNZIP "%%i" && GOTO DONE || GOTO DONE
:DONE
```

The differences are:

- The "tokens=*" option returns the whole of the filename even if it contains spaces.
- The filename passed to UNZIP is quoted
- This variant uses single quotes for the DIR command so doesn't need the "usebackq" option.

Answer (score 2):

If Cygwin or other Unix-like environment is an alternative

```
unzip "$(ls -tr *zip | tail -n1)"
```

would do it

Comment: You can also download http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/ and add it to your path to let you use a lot of the standard Unix utilities from a command prompt -- a must have on my Windows machines so in case I forget dir vs. ls, cat vs. type, etc.  Nice to have grep, awk, and such too.

Comment: Sorry, correcting that last link -- looks like they've moved stuff around and to get the actual files you have to go to http://sourceforge.net/projects/unxutils

Answer (score -1):

I think you would need 7-zip to be able to script compression/uncompression.

Answer (score -2):

Why use bat files when you have powershell or console applications?